# why struct with error cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct

Here is my code:

```
struct queue {
        int queue_arr[5];
        int rear;
        int front;
};

int main()
{
        struct queue q;
        int choice;

        queue_init(q);
}

queue_init(struct queue *q)
{
        int i = 0;
        q->rear = -1;
        q->front = -1;
        for (; i < MAX; i++) {
                q->queue_arr[i] = 0;
        }
}
```

It causes segmentation error on execution:

```
[root@workmachine test_cpp]# ./queue  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I remove struct I'll use `int queue_arr[5]; int rear; int front;` as global segmentation error disappears. Why? and how to to avoid it whit using of structs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the address:

```
queue_init(&q);
           ^
```

I'm surprised it compiles as it stands.

Comment: `queue_init()` is not declared before it is invoked in `main()`. Perhaps this allows the compiliation to succeed, with warnings?

Comment: Yes, I paid attention on it too, but gcc does not return any warning.

Comment: If you declared the function or prototype for `queue_init` before `main` you would have mostly likely gotten an error (clang gives one). Do not ignore warnings.